# Chrome ignores link to external protocol

Tags: url, web-development, links, google-chrome

When I click on a button, the href is for the external protocol `mayApp://`. Chrome ignores this.  I want it to show it somehow (address bar is preferable).

I use web automation to verify this link.

I have tried to change `chrome advanced settings` but it didn't help. Do I have to write a chrome extension to fetch this link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assuming that `mayApp:` may be a typo where mayApp is meant to be myApp. Please forgive my ignorance in this area. However, neither of these seem to be recognized by standards.

You can find most if not all recognized URI schemes here:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URI_scheme#Official_IANA-registered_schemes

To quote:

> A URI scheme is the top level of the uniform resource identifier (URI)
>   naming structure in computer networking. All URIs and absolute URI
>   references are formed with a scheme name, followed by a colon
>   character (":"), and the remainder of the URI called (in the outdated
>   RFCs 1738 and 2396, but not the current STD 66/RFC 3986) the
>   scheme-specific part. The syntax and semantics of the scheme-specific
>   part are left largely to the specifications governing individual
>   schemes, subject to certain constraints such as reserved characters
>   and how to "escape" them.
>
> URI schemes are frequently and incorrectly referred to as "protocols",
>   or specifically as URI protocols or URL protocols, since most were
>   originally designed to be used with a particular protocol, and often
>   have the same name. The http scheme, for instance, is generally used
>   for interacting with web resources using HyperText Transfer Protocol.
>   Today, URIs with that scheme are also used for other purposes, such as
>   RDF resource identifiers and XML namespaces, that are not related to
>   the protocol. Furthermore, some URI schemes are not associated with
>   any specific protocol (e.g. "file") and many others do not use the
>   name of a protocol as their prefix (e.g. "news").

You will find in this list a URI scheme for `app:`.

It is likely that the browser you are using does not recognize the URI scheme you are trying to reference and therefore does not support it.

Comment: then how can i force it to show something when not supported? Now it just does nothing

Comment: You can't. Simply put, the browser is not coded to recognize anything other than what standards exist. Change mayApp to app which is supported.

Comment: I cannot change "myApp" scheme, as I'm testing something that should happen in my android app as an intent with this specific scheme.